# Vuepress site not loading properly when deployed on github pages

Tags: github-pages, vuepress

The website loads on my localhost perfectly fine as below.

[image: Works fine]

But the problem when deployed to gh-pages, it looks like below. Looks like it is not reading `config.js` file from the `docs/.vuepress/` folder.

[image: Not working fine]

While deploying to github pages, it is said to add `base: <REPO Name>`, I did that as well. In my [Repository](https://github.com/sachinkmohan/sacmoncodes2), it is currently removed.

What am I missing here? Please help.

Your are free to check out my [Repository](https://github.com/sachinkmohan/sacmoncodes2) and see if you can help. Thanks in advance!!